# Which is the correct use of these prepositions?

Tags: prepositions

Trying to discern correct use of prepositions. Here's the sentence as I have it:

> This was proof that he could stay steadfast under conditions in which other men could not!

Should it be: "...under conditions which other men..." ?

Or is there another way that's more correct?

Comment: The bad guy is *in which*, a trap for backhanded constructions to ambush the best. 
Reword!

Comment: @YosefBaskin thanks.

Comment: You could repeat 'under' giving "... under conditions under which other men could not."